# Try to disable the word highlight feature in vs code, failed after a lot of try

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know this question is simple and stupid. But I almost disable all the highlight features in my vscode and I also uninstall all extensions about highlight features. It still doesn't work, vscode still highlight each word of current line automatically. What did I miss?[image]

Comment: change the theme to default and check

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Can you share the screenshot with default theme?

Comment: you still have gitlens enabled, try it with the insiders version without ANY extension, or use the `disable all extensions` on the extension bar top menu

Comment: I found it is background phi colors extension, thanks all.